# VisualStateManager.GoToState returns false and Visual State is not changed

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, visualstatemanager

I have this XAML code:

```
       <Button x:Name="btnStartRecord" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Button.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3883E" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.BorderBrush>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="btnStopRecord" Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Button.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3883E" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.BorderBrush>
        </Button>

<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="MainStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="RecordIconState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="btnStartRecord" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="Visible"/>
                            <!--<DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>-->
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="btnStopRecord" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="StopRecordIconState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <!--<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="btnStartRecord" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="btnStopRecord" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>                
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

And in Code Behind, I call following function in OnLoad/Constructor :

```
private void SwitchRecordButtonContent()
    {
        {
            if (m_bRecording)
            {
                //btnStartStopRecord.Content = "StopRecord";
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, StopRecordIconState.Name, false);
                VisualState currentState = MainStates.CurrentState;
                Visibility temp = btnStartRecord.Visibility;
            }
            else
            {
                //btnStartStopRecord.Content = "StartRecord";
                bool op = VisualStateManager.GoToState((Button)this.btnStartRecord, RecordIconState.Name, false); // I get this always false
                VisualState currentState = MainStates.CurrentState;
                Visibility temp = btnStartRecord.Visibility;
            }
        }
    }
```

But I see no Visual state change and I cannot figure out why :(

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the VSM attached to the root element?

Comment: yes it is, to the grid around above xaml code.

Comment: @atomaras Thanks a lot.
Even though the VAM was attached to the root of my context, there was additional Grid around it.
I tried attaching it to that one and it worked! Great!!
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as atomaras mentioned in above comment, moved the code to the very root of the usercontrol
and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

You are calling

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState((Button)this.btnStartRecord, RecordIconState.Name, false); // I get this always false
```

but based on a short glance you should be calling

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, RecordIconState.Name, false);
```

Comment: BTW, I like the idea of getting a name of a named state to use when transitioning to that state. Where did you get that from? I need to start doing it too.

Comment: Hi Filip,
I tried both the ways. If you see, in IF part I tried sending "this"
but it didn't work. So I tried button which didn't work either.

naming in that style I used for my own convenience. The code is too big, so to simplify getting what it's exactly doing after few days it's written, I used it.

Nice that you liked it. Many people don't like it :)

By the way if you find any other way of solving the problem, please let me know. Thanks :)